# jQuery evangelists!

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, json

I'm absolutely digging what I've been able to do in jQuery.  From my perspective there isn't a lot jQuery can't do.

I'm working on a new project and my plan is to use jQuery heavily with JSON,Ajax and Webservices inside of a ASP.net project.

Before I go spouting my opinion about how great jQuery is, I thought I might ask if there are any downsides to jQuery.

I know it is a little subjective, but it still relates to a programming question and there may be answers to common myths about jQuery (for and against).

**::UPDATE::**

I just figured a question like that may of been helpful to a lot of people just trying to learn jQuery. I have only seen upside, but there are a lot of people out there that might know something or have seen something where it doesn't work. I figured it would be closed due to the subjective nature but I was hoping it would stay open a little longer...

Comment: Try again with just "Downsides to jQuery in regards to other javascript frameworks". But subjective questions are not really tolerated on stackoverflow - don't ask my why, I don't know.

Comment: I just figured a question like that may of been helpful to a lot of people just trying to learn jQuery.  I have only seen upside, but there are a lot of people out there that might know something or have seen something where it doesn't work.  I figured it would be closed due to the subjective nature but I was hoping it would stay open a little longer...

Comment: My main complaints with jQuery: 1. the system of adding expandos to every touched element, then regex-hacking away the attributes that result in IE every time `html()` or things that rely on it like `clone()` are used is absolutely appalling, and causes breakage when working together with non-jQuery code; 2. it encourages inappropriate markup creation from unescaped concatenated strings (XSS!), and then also regex-hacks on content creation (see the `clean` function), which is awful;

Comment: 3. it encourages shoehorning everything into selectors, again with escaping problems (and it doesn't parse all selectors properly either); 4. some methods are excessively overloaded, in particular the `$` function which confusingly does several unrelated things; 5. when chaining is used not always clear; 6. lack of select-one functionality means when you accidentally fail to select any element you won't notice the error straight away, and operations that make sense on one element are mixed with operations that make sense on many;

Comment: 7. its complete-replacement-for-DOM style of API encourages doing some operations in a very roundabout way that would be much simpler and faster in plain DOM; 8. `attr()` tries to pretend that attributes and properties are the same thing, with confusing consequences; 9. the code itself is written in an unclear and maze-like fashion. Having said all this, the other frameworks I've used have problems that are at least as bad. No-one's yet found the perfect compromise for making framework functions and plain JS/DOM blend nicely.

Comment: That was a good answer...  Too bad the question is closed as I think that your opinions are valid.